# converting dataset yolo v3 pytorch format to required format

Tags: python, java, github, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to implement the conversion discussed in the blogspot https://medium.com/@alexppppp/how-to-annotate-keypoints-using-roboflow-9bc2aa8915cd.
In my dataset I need 4 keypoints and 1 box. I want the edited code for it.

My code and error are shown below.

```
keypoint_names = ['Head', 'Tail']
rectangles2keypoints = {1:0, 2:1}

def converter(file_labels, file_image, keypoint_names):

img = cv2.imread(file_image)
img_w, img_h = img.shape[1], img.shape[0]

with open(file_labels) as f:
    lines_txt = f.readlines()
    lines = []
    for line in lines_txt:
        lines.append([int(line.split()[0])] + [round(float(el), 5) for el in line.split()[1:]])

bboxes = []
keypoints = []

# In this loop we convert normalized coordinates to absolute coordinates
for line in lines:
    # Number 0 is a class of rectangles related to bounding boxes.
    if line[0] == 0:
        x_c, y_c, w, h = round(line[1] * img_w), round(line[2] * img_h), round(line[3] * img_w), round(line[4] * img_h)
        bboxes.append([round(x_c - w/2), round(y_c - h/2), round(x_c + w/2), round(y_c + h/2)])

    # Other numbers are the classes of rectangles related to keypoints.
    # After convertion, numbers of keypoint classes should start with 0, so we apply rectangles2keypoints dictionary to achieve that.
    # In our case:
    # 1 is rectangle for head keypoint, which is 0, so we convert 1 to 0;
    # 2 is rectangle for tail keypoint, which is 1, so we convert 2 to 1.
    if line[0] != 0:
        kp_id, x_c, y_c = rectangles2keypoints[line[0]], round(line[1] * img_w), round(line[2] * img_h)
        keypoints.append([kp_id, x_c, y_c])

# In this loop we are iterating over each keypoint and looking to which bounding box it matches.
# Thus, we are matching keypoints and corresponding bounding boxes.
keypoints_sorted = [[[] for _ in keypoint_names] for _ in bboxes]
for kp in keypoints:
    kp_id, kp_x, kp_y = kp[0], kp[1], kp[2]
    for bbox_idx, bbox in enumerate(bboxes):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3]
        if x1 < kp_x < x2 and y1 < kp_y < y2:
            keypoints_sorted[bbox_idx][kp_id] = [kp_x, kp_y, 1] # All keypoints are visible
            
return bboxes, keypoints_sorted
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRLC0.png)

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, please copy and paste the error, don't show an image. See [this explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303816/2257664) about why.